# Android: Trying to have a TextView under a webview, TextView not getting created

Tags: android

I have a layout that has a horizontal container, then 2 vertical containers inside it.
The first vertical container has a web view followed by a textview.  The textview does not get created and the webview fills the height.  I tried to set the height of the web control by
android:layout_height="60px", but it seems like it is not working.

The xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

         <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webAuthor"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"  />

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textChats"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/eventsbakground"  
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView                  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/addbanner"
                android:id="@+id/butAdd"    
                android:layout_gravity="center"   
                android:layout_marginTop="12px" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mylist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>    

        </LinearLayout>                    
    </LinearLayout>          
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to format your xml way better than that. Try ctrl + shift + f for auto format and update the code here afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the ctrl + shift f tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @Vikram  Singh , Remove `android:layout_weight="1.0"`, when you set your view's `layout_weight` to "1.0" it means that this view must fill hole parent.

With `layout_weight` you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a MapView and a table which should show some additional information to the map. The map should use 3/4 of the screen and table should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the layout_weight of the map to 3 and the layout_weight of the table to 1. But When you are setting 1 to only one it'll fill parent

Answer (score 2):

try removing `android:layout_weight="1.0"` from your web view as it may cause webview to capture whole layout and hiding the textview.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the weight is going to override the height inside of your WebView, I'd try removing that.  But as Warren stated, your formatting here on the post was incredibly difficult to read and I'm very grateful that he edited it.